# The horizon of the heptagonal triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

I have discovered this interesting property of the [heptagonal triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagonal_triangle) while making constructions in GeoGebra.

Let $\triangle_0$ be a heptagonal triangle with the [orthocenter](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Orthocenter.html) $H_0$,
$\triangle_1$ the [orthic triangle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthicTriangle.html) of $\triangle_0$ with the orthocenter $H_1$,
...
$\triangle_n$ the orthic triangle of $\triangle_{n-1}$ with the orthocenter $H_n$.

Let $H$ be the [homothetic center](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomotheticCenter.html) of the triangles $\triangle_0$,  $\triangle_2$,  $\triangle_4$, ..., $\triangle_{2k}$.
Obviously, $H$ is also the homothetic center of the triangles $\triangle_1$,  $\triangle_3$,  $\triangle_5$, ..., $\triangle_{2k + 1}$.

It appears all the orthocenters $H_0$, $H_1$, ..., $H_n$ lie on a straight line passing through $H$.
Furthermore, the sequence $H_0$, $H_1$, $H_2$, ... converges to $H$.
Let us name the line *the horizon* of $\triangle_0$.

[image]

Questions:

1. Is there a simple way to prove the existence of the *horizon* of the heptagonal triangle?
2. Are there other interesting properties of the line?
3. Are there other triangles with the same or similar property?

Comment: Because (as is noted in Wikipedia's ["Heptagonal triangle" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagonal_triangle#Orthic_triangle)) the heptagonal triangle is similar to its orthic triangle, "all you have to do" to prove the existence of the horizon line is prove that the first three orthocenters are collinear. With a bit of symbol-crunching in *Mathematica*, I have verified this.

Comment: I have just realized that this is a trivial statement following from the fact that if the triangles are homothetic, their orthocentric systems are homothetic too. Let me know if I should remove the question.

Comment: I don't see a reason to delete the question. (It introduced me to the notion of the heptagonal triangle. :)  You could/should just self-answer it, to get it out of the Unanswered queue.